# How is $\alpha =2 \beta$?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a solved example in 'Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes' by George F.Simmons.

> Find the shape of a curved mirror such that light from a
> source at the origin will be reflected in a beam of rays parallel to the
> $x$-axis.
> Solution :
> By symmetry, the mirror will have the shape of the surface of revolution
> generated by revolving a curve $APB$ ( [figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uh8n9.jpg) ) about the $x$-axis.
> It follows from the law of reflection that $α = 2β$. By the geometry of the
> situation, $ϕ = β $ and $θ = α + ϕ = 2β$.  .....

This is a part of the solution and I understood the following statements. But I do not understand how it is concluded that by laws of reflection $\alpha = 2\beta$. Shouldn't it be $\alpha =\beta$ since angle of reflection must be equal to angle of incidence?

Comment: Looks like a typo. Note that $\phi=\beta$ and $\alpha+\phi=2\beta$ also imply $\alpha=\beta$. Possibly the author was mixing angles up with slope (as the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$).